# Javascript to insert IFRAME

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'd like to give people the ability to insert a single Javascript line into their site which effectively allows me to insert an IFRAME of a fixed size that contains content from my site.  It's effectively a widget which allows them to search my site or receive other information.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
You can use document.createElement("iframe") and then appendChild() or replaceChild() the new element =/  [if you use replaceChild, you define a dummy div that has the width/height of your iframe]

Or am I interpreting your question incorrectly?

Comment: That's great.  I'm going to try this out.

Comment: K, I have no life so I'll check back often.  If you have any questions feel free to ask via commenting on this answer =/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suedo code for guaranteed insertion and loading of iframe

```
var __IE__ = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0 ;
var iframe=document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src="__URL__";

if(document.reayState === "complete" || ( __IE__ && document.readyState === "interactive" )){

       document.body.appendChild(iframe);

}else{          
      if(__IE__){
         document.onreadystatechange = function(){
           if(document.readyState === "complete"){
                document.onreadystatechange = null;
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
           }
         };
      }else{
         var callback = function(){
              if(document.removeEventListener){
                   document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",callback,false);
              }
              window.onload = function(){};
              document.body.appendChild(iframe);
         }

         if(document.addEventListener){
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",callback,false);
         }
         window.onload = callback;


      }

}
```

If document state is loading prefer document.write , else you can use above code.