# Inserting an iFrame with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Taking inspiration from [Javascript to insert IFRAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337010/javascript-to-insert-iframe), I am trying to insert an iFrame via Javascript:

```
function display(selector) {

    var i = document.createElement('iframe');
    i.scrolling = 'no';
    i.frameborder = '0';
    i.allowtransparency = 'true';
    i.style.border = 'none';
    i.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    i.style.width = $(selector).css('width');
    i.style.height = $(selector).css('height');
    i.src = '//localhost/content';
    $(selector).append(i);
}
```

Forgive the lazy jQuery.

Anyway, this works as expected on Firefox, but Chrome bails out with the following error:

```
Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

Chrome does add the expected HTML, but doesn't display the iFrame. What's the reason for this and, if there is one, what's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work for me, maybe you need to add a port to your localhost url.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/AR326/)

```
function display(selector) {

    var i = document.createElement('iframe');
    i.scrolling = 'no';
    i.frameborder = '0';
    i.allowtransparency = 'true';
    i.style.border = 'none';
    i.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    i.style.width = $(selector).css('width');
    i.style.height = $(selector).css('height');
    i.src = 'http://www.wikipedia.com';
    $(selector).append(i);
}

display($('#cont'));
```

html:

```
<div id="cont"></div>
```

css:

```
#cont {
     width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

personally i would use a function like this, and do the rest with css:

```
function iframeIt(where, url) {
    where.append('<iframe src="' + url + '"></iframe>');
}

iframeIt($('#cont'), 'http://www.wikipedia.com');
```